# Django template language checking the value

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I need to check if value in m2mfield of django and then get it selected if it is

```
<option value="Clothes" {% if "Clothes" in product.categories.all %} selected {% endif %}>Clothes</option>
```

i tried this but seems like it doesnt work
the view function

```
def update_page(request, param):
    if request.method == "POST":
        product = Product.objects.get(pk=param)
        print(request.POST.getlist('categories'))
        data = request.POST
        title = data.get('title')
        categories = data.getlist('categories')
        price = data.get('price')
        description = data.get('description')
        rating = data.get('rating')
        product.title = title
        product.categories.clear()
        for i in categories:
            product.categories.add(Category.objects.get(title=i))
            print(i)
        product.price = price
        product.description = description
        product.rating = rating
        product.save()
        # if data.get('test'):
        #     print("loh")
        # else:
        #     print("not found")
        return redirect('product', param=param)

    else:
        product = Product.objects.get(pk=param)
        context = {
            "product": product
        }
        return render(request, "update.html", context=context)
```

Comment: Can you share the view that renders the template?

Answer (score 0):

The `product.categories.all` returns a queryset of category objects and you are checking a string with it which won't work. You can define a [custom](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#how-to-create-custom-template-tags-and-filters) template tag that checks for the existence of category like this:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def has_category(queryset, title):
    return title in list(queryset.values_list('title', flat=True))
```

and then use it like this in your template:

```
<option value="Clothes" {% if product.categories.all|has_category|"Clothes" %} selected {% endif %}>Clothes</option>
```

don't forget to load your template tag in your template `{% load custom_tags %}`